# HTML / CSS table has different height in Internet Explorer than in Chrome

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm trying to create a heatmap using html, css, javascript. 
I got everything working perfect... in Chrome. In Internet Explorer, the table cells are 3-4 times taller, so the table looks weird. The picture below shows how it looks in Chrome.
[image]

This picture is from Internet Explorer
[image]

This is my css.

```
table {
    tr th {
      vertical-align: middle;

      &.xLabel {
        text-align: center;
      }
      &.yLabel {
        text-align: right;
      }

    }

    tr {

      td {
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        height: 30px;
      }

    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea for a fix?

Comment: Tried using `em` units for height?

Comment: @Swordys em does not work

Comment: Try this : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to default properties, which differ from browser to browser.

So you should overwrite as many of them as needed (even when here they don't seem to differ [see note below]): `font-family`, `font-size`, `line-height`, `padding`, `margin`... and everything else I don't have at mind now.

Note: not only browser default properties may differ, but also user preferences may overwrite them in any way.
So you should enforce *all* possibly involved properties *even if your tests doesn't show any difference*.